# Mapping a 3D point inside a hexahedron to a unit cube

Tags: matrices, solid-geometry

Let **A<sub>4x8</sub>** be a hexahedron defined by 8 points in 3D homogeneous coordinates.

**M<sub>8x8</sub>** is a map that transforms the hexahedron to a unit cube, **B<sub>4x8</sub>**.

If **A = B . M**, then

**M = B<sup>-1</sup> . A**

How can I map a 3D point, **P<sub>4x1</sub>** in **A** to **B** using **M**?

---

Example:

**A** = \begin{bmatrix}
-0.909198 & -0.717041 & -0.745330 & -0.938879 & -1.435481 & -1.196454 & -1.231644 & -1.472402 \\
0.867548 & 0.893142 & 0.633169 & 0.615845 & 1.071125 & 1.102962 & 0.779577 & 0.758028 \\
2.259478 & 2.391340 & 2.435814 & 2.300889 & 2.942843 & 3.106868 & 3.162191 & 2.994355 \\
1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0
\end{bmatrix}

**B** = \begin{bmatrix}
0.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0\\
1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 0.0 & 0.0\\
0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 0.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0\\
1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0 & 1.0
\end{bmatrix}

**P** = \begin{bmatrix}
-1.052645\\
0.833213\\
2.661413\\
1.0
\end{bmatrix}

Comment: What is **your** definition of a hexaedron ? There are many candidates (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexahedron)!

Comment: @JeanMarie A pyramidal frustrum

Comment: Why $M$ is  $8 \times 8$? If you used homogeneous coordinates it would be easier to use    $4 \times 4$ matrix $M$ ...and in this case $ A=MB$.

Comment: @Widawensen I tried that, but then when you try to inverse transform **B** to **A**, I wasn't getting the unit cube, it was slightly different. Is it due to insufficient degrees of freedom?

Comment: @ns88 you have to much data .. you can used any subset of linearly independent 4 columns of $B$ and made from them $ 4 \times 4$ matrix $B'$, it should be invertible. Of course from $A$ 4 columns should also be selected appropriately . Generally try to operate on  $ 4 \times 4$ matrices.

Comment: Is this pyramidal frustrum can be seen as the truncation of a "Egyptian style pyramid" (with its apex at the vertical of the center of the base square) by a plane parallel to the base plane, or more general than that ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The axis is perpendicular to both bases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $A_i (x_i,y_i,z_i)^T (0 \leq i \leq 7) $ the 8 vertices of the hexahedron with their 3D coordinates (we don't need the 4th projective coordinate).

I don't need to assume that the hexahedron is a regular pyramid frutrum.

If the unit cube is defined by coordinates $\{0,1\}^3$, a convenient mapping is as follows :

$$\tag{1}(u,v,w) \in [0,1]^3 \ \ \mapsto \ \ \left\{\begin{array}{rl}(1-u)(1-v)(1-w) & \hspace{-0.5em}A_0 \ \ +\\
                    (1-u)(1-v)w & \hspace{-0.5em} A_1 \ \ +\\
                    (1-u)v(1-w) &\hspace{-0.5em}A_2 \ \ +\\
                     (1-u)vw & \hspace{-0.5em}A_3 \ \ +\\
                    u(1-v)(1-w)& \hspace{-0.5em}A_4 \ \ +\\
                    u(1-v)w& \hspace{-0.5em}A_5 \ \ +\\
                    uv(1-w)& \hspace{-0.5em}A_6 \ \ +\\
                     uvw&\hspace{-0.5em}A_7\end{array}\right.$$

**Short explanation:** 2 "ingredients":

1) Boolean logic (even if $u,v,w$ are reals): for example, vertex $A_6$ (and only this vertex) is "triggered" iff $(u,v,w)=(1,1,0)$ which is the binary representation of number 6.

2) Convex hull building: if the hexahedron is convex, the fact that $u,v,w \in [0,1]$ implies that each coefficient, from $(1-u)(1-v)(1-w)$ to $uvw$ is in $[0,1]$. Morever, one can prove that (1) is a bijection, because each point can be described in this way.

**Remark:** Of course, an important simplication occurs in the case of a pyramid frustrum.

---

**Edit:** How to build a function in the other way : Frustrum $\mapsto$ Cube.

As it is likely that you know projective transforms, here is a solution that uses them.

Let $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ the basis of your frustrum. Let $S$ be the summit (apex) of the pyramid.

The projective matrix $P$ that maps  Frustrum $\mapsto$ Cube is such that:

$$\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_C=P\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_S\\
y_1 & y_2 & y_3 & y_S\\
z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & z_S\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1
\end{bmatrix}}_F$$

In particular $P$ maps $\begin{bmatrix}
x_S\\
y_S\\
z_S\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ onto $\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{bmatrix}$ (apex is sent to the point at infinity - last coordinate $0$ - in the right direction ; this is what could be called "the opening of the cube")

Thus, one has to compute:

$$P=CF^{-1}$$

Let $P_{ij}$ be the entries of $P$ ; then the transformation equations are:

$$\begin{cases}X=\frac{P_{11}x+P_{12}y+P_{13}z+P_{14}}{P_{41}x+P_{42}y+P_{43}z+P_{44}}\\Y=\frac{P_{21}x+P_{22}y+P_{23}z+P_{24}}{P_{41}x+P_{42}y+P_{43}z+P_{44}}\\Z=\frac{P_{31}x+P_{32}y+P_{33}z+P_{34}}{P_{41}x+P_{42}y+P_{43}z+P_{44}}\\\end{cases}$$

Remark: you will probably need to take $\begin{bmatrix}
kx_S\\
ky_S\\
kz_S\\
k
\end{bmatrix}$ with a certain coefficient $k$ instead of $\begin{bmatrix}
x_S\\
y_S\\
z_S\\
1
\end{bmatrix}$ in order to take into account the heigth where the cut is done in the pyramid.

Here is a Matlab program that can help you:

> > ```
> > clear all;
> >
> > C = [0     1     1     0
> >      0     0     1     0
> >      0     0     0     1
> >      1     1     1     0];
> >
> > H = 5;    %height of pyramid
> > k = 1.5;  % coefficient k has been obtained by trial and error
> >           % in order that(as an example) the frustrum's height is exactly 3 
> > x1 = 3;  y1 = 3;  z1 = 0;
> > x2 = 5;  y2 = 3;  z2 = 0;
> > x3 = 5;  y3 = 5;  z3 = 0;
> > xS = 4;  yS = 4;  zS = H;
> >
> > k = 1;
> >
> > F = [x1 x2 x3 k*xS
> >      y1 y2 y3 k*yS
> >      z1 z2 z3 k*H
> >       1  1  1 k];
> >
> > P = C * F^(-1);
> > X = @(x,y,z)(P(1,:)*[x,y,z,1]');
> > Y = @(x,y,z)(P(2,:)*[x,y,z,1]');
> > Z = @(x,y,z)(P(3,:)*[x,y,z,1]');
> > T = @(x,y,z)(P(4,:)*[x,y,z,1]');
> >
> > % k = Z(xS,yS,h) ./ T(xS,yS,h);
> > % x=4;y=4;z=0; %is send onto point 0.5 0.5 0
> > % x=5;y=5;z=0; %is send onto point 1 1 0
> > % x=4;y=4;z=3; %is send onto point 0.5 0.5 1
> >
> > Xp = X(x,y,z) ./ T(x,y,z);
> > Yp = Y(x,y,z) ./ T(x,y,z);
> > Zp = Z(x,y,z) ./ T(x,y,z);
> >
> > fprintf('The image of %s %s %s is %s %s %s\n',...
> > num2str(x),num2str(y),num2str(z),num2str(Xp),num2str(Yp),num2str(Zp));
> > ```

Comment: Could you comment on this solution ? Is it understandable ?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. I wrote a program and it works fine. But I'm not sure how to do the inverse mapping.

Comment: ...since the frustum is not in [0,1]

Comment: Happy you finally answered. I don't understand what you mean by "the frustum is not in [0,1]" ? The transformation I gave sends the reference (i.e., abstract) cube with points $(u,v,w) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \times [0,1]$ onto any hexahedron. I suggest you draw a figure with all available information in order to avoid misunderstandings: this should a prerequisite for all geometrical issues...

Comment: Mapping from cube to frustum is working fine, it is the inverse mapping that I'm stuck at. The coordinates of the frustum need not be in [0,1], for e.g. a point, P, in the frustum may be [-11.1, 22.2, -33.3]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58252/discussion-between-jeanmarie-and-nsn88).

Comment: Any update on this?

Comment: Could you first answer  to my previous question : "Could you give an example of the coordinates of the vertices of the frustrum and of the cube. I don't see for example if you want to keep the same square base for the frustrum and the cube." It is very  important for a new solution that I have in mind.

Comment: I just saw you have included such an example in your text.

Comment: Its supposed to be a frustum, I'll check again.

Comment: Btw, isn't it possible to map any convex hexahedron (not just a frustum) to a cube?

Comment: Yes, of course, it is what my equations do (in the other direction, I agree). But seing that your frustum wasn't... a frustrum, I asked myself if I had well understood...

Comment: I've updated the question with new example data. I guess the old example had rounding errors.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution?

Comment: At last, I have found some time to answer you (see the edit I have made to my answer)

Comment: Why isn't **B4** used in the equations? Is it because a rectangular base is assumed?

Comment: I will answer your question. But first, let me say that a little "thanks" beginning your answer would have been welcome :)

Comment: Sorry for being cold. I'm new to this site, and took MSE's comment guidelines (Avoid comments like "+1" or "thanks") a bit too seriously. I really appreciate the time you've put in to help me find a solution. :)

Comment: I understand. Adding these little signs contribute to a very very tiny fraction of global warming, but add a real warming in exchanges. More seriously, I have added to my answer a Matlab program that can help you, even if you don't work with this langage. About your last question, yes, $B_4$ is supposed, being fourth vertex of the frustrum's base, to "follow the move".

Comment: I rectify in my text a very erroneous $(0.5, 0.5, 0, 0)^T$ into $(0,0,1,0)^T$ (point at infinity in the direction of $z$ axis); It was already rectified in the program I have given.

Comment: Absolutely, it is the little things that make life good :)

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with Matlab, will check how this works out and keep you  posted. Thank you for saving me the coding time.